# Deleting custom cell in Table View

Tags: iphone

I am using a `Table View Cell` to draw custom cell in table view. Now the problem is that when I try to delete the cell in editing style  `UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete` only the 
the little red -ve sign bitton appear and when I click it nothing happen.

Please help me and tell me how to delete custom cell in table view

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gyani its not at all possible that when you click on (-) sign nothing happens.

May be your tables user interaction is disabled. Try enabling `tableView.userInteractionEnabled=YES`

And still it does not work then post some code.

hAPPY cODING...

Answer (score 0):

did you implement the appropriate [delegate methods](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDataSource_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html)? Specifically

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView canEditRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you implement this delegate method by following form?

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
   if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
   {
      // remove the cell from UITableView
      [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:indexPath withRowAnimation:YES];   
      // remove the data from self array or something else.
      ... 
   } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a subview in the cell that stops the user interaction? maybe located in negative x, so it is over the delete button.